# Order of Products proof explanation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, intuition

Here $a,b$...etc are decomposed cycle and they form permutation.

Let $a$,$b$ be elements of finite orders $m$ and $n$ respectively in a group $G$. Suppose that $ba=ab$ and that $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle=\{e\}$. Then the order of $ab$ is the l.c.m. of $m$ and $n$.

Proof:

Let $l=mp=nq$ be l.c.m. of $m$ and $n$. Then $(ab)^l=a^lb^l=a^{mp}b^{nq}=(a^m)^p(b^n)^q=e^pe^q=e$. (Here $e$ is identity) so the order of $ab$ is at most $l$. Now let $k>0$ and suppose that $(ab)^k=e$. Then $a^kb^k=e$ so $a^k=b^{-k}$. But then $a^k\in\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle$ so $a^k=e$. Similarly, $b^k=e$. $k$ is common multiple of $m$ and $n$ so $k\ge l$. Thuse, the order of $ab$ is at least $l$. As we have already seen that it is at most $l$, it must be $l$

Why would $a^k\in\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle$? Was it a suppose statement? Another problem is why is $k\ge l$? Why shouldn't it be $k\le l$?

Comment: Since $a^k=b^{n-k}$, this element can be generated by either $a$ or $b$, so $a^k\in<a>\cap<b>$

Comment: Since $k$ is a common multiple of $m,n$, it must be greater than or equal to $l$ since the assumption is that $l$ is the $\operatorname{lcm}$ which is the least common multiple. By this argument, we are trying to show that for every $k$ that suffices $(ab)^k=e$ we must have $k\geqslant l$. If $k< l$ then $l$ would no longer be the order of $ab$ and thus the whole point of this argument would be of no use.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang I can't believe your statement. I think I can say you are wrong at first statement. $a^k=b^{n-k}$ can only be generated by $a$ and $b$ and I don't know if $a^k$ should be elements of $<a>\cap<b>$ since the only element  $<a>\cap<b>$ have is $e$ so first $a^k$ should be $e$ so I guess it is assumed $a^k=e$ or else I don't know how from fest step we know $a^k=e$.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang but both $k$ and $l$ are lcm so they should be equal. I want to know the greater part.

Comment: Your doubt is reasonable. There are two things we know for sure: (1) $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle$ only contains $e$; and (2) by definitions of $\langle a\rangle,\langle b\rangle$ and the fact that $a^k$ is also a power of $b$ ($b^{-k}=b^{n-k}$), this element $a^k$ must be in the intersection. Thus, $a^k$ must be $e$ and therefore $k$ is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: Also, we apply this argument to $a$ and $b$ to show that $m\mid k$ and $n\mid k$. Therefore, $k$ is **one of the common multiples** of $m,n$, but NOT necessarily the least one. $l$ is the least one.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang Ah now I get it. I was viewing common multiplier as lcm which is my mistake. And I understood what you mean by $a^k$ they must exist in the intersection of cyclic group a and b because $a^k=b^{-k} $ which means $b^{-k}\in b$. Thanks! Now I understand.

Comment: I am glad to hear that.